# Should not allow allows continuous use of special characters in email validation

Tags: regex, angular, validation, email, expression

User is not allow to enter special character as the first character of email address, Also
not allows continuous use of special characters
eg: !aman%^&*?'}{!josgi@uhsafj.com

Comment: Why do you want to block valid emails? Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 2):

An exact implementation of your requirements might be:

```
^(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9]{2})[A-Za-z0-9].*$
```

This would forbid the password starting with a non alphanumeric character, and would also not allow two non alphanumeric symbols from occurring in succession.

Comment: I was thinking just `^(?!.*\W\W)`, because it's shorter, but also because underscore should not be considered a "special" characer IMHO. I actually know someone who has two consecutive underscores in their email address.